# Add a Regular Modal for an Image using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image, modal-dialog

I need to create a "lightbox". I am approaching this problem in two steps so that I can grasp it better and understand what is going on, instead of just copying code online. First, I want to create a Modal for an Image that I have on the screen. Most of the tutorials online that deal with creating modals use a button to trigger it, but I desperately need to use a picture only. Once I have created the modal, I will incorporate a carousel into the body of the modal.

I have tried to copy a lot of code but none of it has worked for me. One seemingly appeared as if it would work, the modal existed after I clicked on the image but it didn't display. When I clciked inspect, I saw the modal and all its content on the side of the webpage, as if it was hiding before but now had appeared. Apparently, it wasn't center, but I didn't know which class to use to center that div.

This is the code I want to place the modal within:

```
  <div class="box three">
          <section class="utopia-box">
            <a data-toggle="modal" id="image-modal" href="#myModal" class="">
            <img src="public/utopia/buildutopia.png" alt="cover">
          </a>
          </section>
          <section class="china-box">
            <img src="public/derivaschina/towercover.png" alt="viewofcity" data-toggle="modal" data-target="">
          </section>

              <section class="map-box">
                <img src="public/geodesign/geodesignmap.png" alt="map">
              </section>

            </div>
```

I need to reproduce a lightbox carousel for all three sections/images. Like I said I want to start with just a modal but all advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using Bootstrap, so you modal body would be just the image (and anything else you wanted to show, in theory). And for each button you'd pass the url of the image clicked via `data` attributes such as:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src=""/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And for each button you'd pass the url of the image clicked via `data` attributes such as:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-image-url="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</a>
```

That would at least get you a working modal with the content you want. Here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/x8nehgL9/17/) NOTE: this just demos the modal opening and closing, not a full carousel, but BS has one of [those](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/carousel/) too. You should also take a look a the docs too: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/

Comment: Oh no sorry, what I meant was that each of those images should have their own modals. To specify, each image is a case study of a project I have done. So when I click on one of the images I need a unique modal to open up for each one. I think the problem lies somewhere else. I actually got a modal working now! The only problem is that it is not displaying on the view where the images are, in fact, they appear a page below( I have a horizontal scroll so it appears on the next page) do you know what could be the problem? This has happened twice now.

Comment: I actually tried what you suggested. It worked but the same probelm occured, it doesn't appear on the main view. It seems to live somewhere outside of the main view, and because a modal is stuck in position untill it is closed, i can't actually check where it is located.

Comment: In this example that you gave above, which class would I have to use in CSS to move it right, or left, up and down. is it possible to move a modal in these directions. should I declare the modal a position such as relative, absolute, etc.

Comment: I think this has something to do with how I made my horizontal scrolling page. Though, it is scrolling horizontally, I made it so that I only need to scroll up and down. I could elaborate as needed.

Comment: Bootstrap out of the box should always be show a modal in the middle of the screen. Are you adding any custom CSS to the modal? Do you have a working fiddle or example of the problem?

Comment: @moi.herrera I updated my answer to reflect it being more inline with your original intent. I think the way you're doing lateral (horizontal) scroll could be causing problem with where the modal shows up.

Comment: I actually fixed the problem! Thanks though. The problem was that the parent elements were using position: relative or absolute. I read on another Stackoverflow post that this was a problem for several people. The solution is to place the modal right under the body, right before any other content/tags/html is coded.